# How to check if the second method make any fail?

Tags: php, laravel

I have these two method in `index` check if the request is approved do loop for products and check the there is enough qty if there is not just return back with message!

The Code

```
public function index(Order $order,Request $request)
{
    if($request->status == 'approved'){
        $this->check($order);
    }

    $this->updateOrder($order,$request);

    return redirect()->back()
            ->with('success',trans('site.message_updated'));
}


protected function check($order){
    foreach($order->products as $product){
        if ($product->doesNotHaveEnoughQuantity($product->pivot->quantity)) {
            return redirect()->back()
                    ->with('error',trans('site.larger_than_qty_in_store'));
        }
        $this->updateProductQty($product);
    }
}
```

When I do make the status `approved` the status is update even the is no enought qty

IN short the redirect back() in `check` does not kill page and stop!

How can I redirect back when I call another method ?

Comment: You need to ensure that the `doesNotHaveEnoughQuantity` method behaves as expected.

Comment: @user3532758 there is no error in the code and when I just move the foreach in check method to index one all things is worked perfectly, but my problem with the return back when I put the foreach in separate method

Comment: That doesnt make sense, not to me at least. If that method returns true it should hit the return statement. Can you do `dd("inside if")` inside the `if` right before `return redirect()..`. See if it get dded.

Comment: @user3532758 yeah i did it and i got the dd result ( maybe you got it wrong, the code is worked and the message of redirect show up, but the return back does not kill the page and the other method like updateOrder worked also which i don't wanna get there cuz it redirect back why the other method  works!? ) that's my problem

Comment: I definitely got it wrong if you got the result. Maybe do a `return false` from the method. Return the updateQty or return a true at the end of the function. And in the index `if( ! $this->check($order) )` do the return back, cos it could be that you need to return the check function from the index functions as well..

Comment: Can you please share the code in for doesNotHaveEnoughQuantity method

Comment: @user3532758 can you pls put it in the answer ? I cannot read the commend right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private $productWithError;

public function index(Order $order,Request $request)
{
    if($request->status == 'approved'){
        if( ! $this->check($order) ) {
            return redirect()->back()
                    ->with('error', $this->productWithError.' '.trans('site.larger_than_qty_in_store'));
        }
    }

    $this->updateOrder($order,$request);

    return redirect()->back()
            ->with('success',trans('site.message_updated'));
}


protected function check($order){
    foreach($order->products as $product){
        if ($product->doesNotHaveEnoughQuantity($product->pivot->quantity)) {
            $this->productWithError = $product->name;
            return false;
        }
        $this->updateProductQty($product);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Worked thanks! is there any better way like keep the  controller more readable

Comment: I just ask cuz I have in the error message the name of product like this (->with('error','( '. $product->name  .' )'.trans('site.larger_than_qty_in_store')); ). your code perfect worked but I have to delete the name of product !

Comment: Oh, you can perhaps have a calss variable to contain the product name that gives you the error. But, that may not be the cleanest way. I am not an expert on clean code but have a look through this for some best practices. https://laravel-news.com/clean-code-php-guide. I've updated the answer.